# QGIS can't connect to PostGIS but pgAdmin4 works

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a PostGIS DB at a remote server and I can connect to it from my desktop using pgAdmin4. However, when I try to connect though QGIS (v3.4) I get an error:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.1.<complete ip here>..., user "car_r" database "car", SSL off
```

The funny thing is that my computer is listed on the server `pg_hba.conf` or else I would not be able to connect using pgAdmin4.

Any idea what could be wrong?

*Adding more info*

My PostGIS server is setup to accept only secure connections (`hostssl` in the `pg_hba.conf`). When I force QGIS to use SSL, (`SSL mode: require`) I get a **"SSL error: certificate verify failed"** error.

How can I make QGIS recognize my server certificate?

Comment: is 10.1.x.x the only ip address your machine has? do you have ipv6 enabled? what is the relevant line from your hba file?

Comment: Our network has ipv6 enabled. I don't have access to the pg_hba.conf file so I don't know how it was done on the server. Will go after my sysadmin.

Comment: do you type a passwd in pgadmin4? - might be set to trust or peer which will fail when QGIS sends a password

Comment: I type a password on both pgadmin and QGIS

Comment: When I wrote that I type a password, I meant that I was using a password. But as I wrote in my answer, the problem happens when I save the password using QGis authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've hit a known QGis bug.

If we use authentication on the PostGIS connection (that is, store the password securely), the connection using SSL fails. If instead I remove my authentication and type the user/password every time, the connection works.

Here is the link to the bug report:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25569

or

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17672