# How to solve root.crt missing in PostgreSQL folder when connecting from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, ssl

I have a PostgreSQL+PostGIS installed on GCP, with SSL/TLS enabled. I can connect just fine from the QGIS Browser panel, but when I try using the Database Manager or Export to PostgreSQL tool I get the below error. I have added the generated certificates and keys in the Authorities and Identities in the Certificate Manager menu.

I can also connect successfully to the DB using the aforementioned certificates from pgAdmin 4 v6.

Similar questions at [Error connecting to a PostgreSQL database from QGIS using SSL certificates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377285) and [QGIS can't connect to PostGIS but pgAdmin4 works](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338391), also [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25569) and [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39648) mentions about being a bug, but the posts are quite old, maybe a solution/workaround exists and I just did not found it yet.

[image]