# QGIS fails to connect sslmode=verify-full consistently with Postgres DB

Tags: qgis, postgis, ssl

I made a PostGIS database (PostgreSQL v15) available for our team to share data as we explore building an application with API access.  (Database has been secured with firewall filters that only allow connections from limited IP addresses and Basic Authentication - username/password and SSL).  I used Let's Encrypt to create SSL certificates for the PostgreSQL database; the Root Certificate for Let's Encrypt is ISRG Root X1 and X2. I am able to use tools like Jetbrains DataGrip to connect to the PostgreSQL database with SSL and the fully qualified domain name without any issues.

We are using QGIS v3.32.0 to create a connection to the PostgreSQL database using the fully qualified domain name and "sslmode=verify-full".  But sometimes QGIS fails and opens the "Enter Credentials" popup box with Realm, Username text entry, Password text entry, and error message, "connection to server at "xxx.xxx.xxxx" (ip address), port, failed: root certificate file "xxxx/postgresql/root.crt" does not exist. Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable to disable server certificate validation."

I verified that QGIS has all of the standard root certificates bundle available to it by going to QGIS Preferences > Authentication > Manage Certificates > Authorities and seeing the Let's Encrypt Root Certificates are available.

[image: QGIS Manage Certificates]

I've searched SO and I've seen [some other posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422086/how-to-solve-root-crt-missing-in-postgresql-folder-when-connecting-from-qgis) from 1.5 years ago about Root certificates not being found by QGIS, but it has not been answered AND it sounds like they did not use Let's Encrypt to generate the SSL certificates for PostgreSQL (it sounds like they generated them using openssl or similar).

1. The other strange behavior is that when we create the QGIS connection and Test Connection, QGIS reports that it is successful. But, later when trying to use the connection to retrieve a saved QGIS project from PostgreSQL, fails with the above message about not being able to find the Root Certificates.  Why is QGIS unable to use the certificate bundle available to it for the root certificate validation?
2. One other strange behavior is that if we turn SSL Mode to "require", the Enter Credentials popup box will still open with "sslmode=verify-full"; not "sslmode=require" as expected. Why is QGIS not changing the SSL Mode flag to "require" when we change it in the QGIS Connections dialog?